# AngularJS and Spring Security. How to handle AngularJS Urls with Spring Security

Tags: spring, url, angularjs, spring-security

Let me explain my problem.
I have implemented a site in AngularJS that is accessed like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/example/resources/#/
```

Here we can call different pages, for example a Login page:

```
http://localhost:8080/example/resources/#/login
```

admin page:

```
http://localhost:8080/example/resources/#/admin
```

user page:

```
http://localhost:8080/example/resources/#/user
```

Now, I have implemented spring security in the example in order to catch every call and check if it has ROLE_USER privileges. So far so good, I have done it like this configuration in Spring security context file:

```
<security:http create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
 authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

    <security:custom-filter ref="customRestFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />       
</security:http>
```

This configuration checks for every url called, if the user has the proper ROLES, and it works fine, throws 401 Unauthorized page.

The problem I`m having is that when I put the login page to be accessed by everybody I'll do  it this way:

```
<security:http create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
 authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

    <security:custom-filter ref="customRestFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" /> 
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />       
</security:http>
```

But I dont know why spring security is not catching this URL. Maybe Angular manages the URL differently.

Finally i have tried deleting the `<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />`  and giving /login** access to ROLE_USER only, but this page was not found. Does anybody know what could be happening here?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So really this has nothing to do with Angular

Comment: Do you understand that all the part of the URL that is after # is seen by the browser only? Angular changes the URL in the address bar, but there is no request made to the server. The only requests made to the server are the AJAX requests used to get the partials and invoke the REST services. That's what you must secure: the REST services.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little [sample application](https://github.com/ghillert/botanic-ng) that illustrates how to integrate [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) with Spring Security by exposing the session id as an HTTP header (x-auth-token). The sample also provides some (simple) authorization (returning the roles from the server) so that the client AngularJS application can react to that. This is of course primarily for user-experience (UX) purposes. Always make sure your REST endpoints have property security.

My blog post on this is **[here](http://www.hillert.blogspot.com/2014/09/secure-your-angularjs-apps-with-spring-session.html)**.